# How to create vertical space, which has a minimum, and is stretchable to \vfill containing the minimum?

Tags: spacing, vspace

How would one create multiple occurrences of vertical space on a page in such a way, that each of them had an individual *minimum amount of space* that would, for each occurrence, be stretched to `fill` only when all the other occurrences with smaller minimums had already been stretched to the minimum of the occurrence in question?

The idea is to stretch all vertical spaces on a page towards equal height (reaching it when possible), filling the page, while ensuring that the absolute requirement of individual minimum amount of space is fulfilled for each of the occurrences. If there is enough unused vertical space on the page, this would result in all the spaces becoming equal regardless of their different minimums.

Here is another, more procedural, way of explaining it. I have multiple vertical spaces on a page. Each of these spaces would have a minimum, which can be different from the others. After fulfilling these requirements for minimum space, if there is still unused space available on the page, I'd like to stretch the spaces. The stretching would happen by enlarging the smallest of the spaces until it (or they, if there are multiple equal spaces) becomes equal to the second smallest space, after which the stretching is repeated on the now smallest spaces. This is repeated as long as there is unused space on the page or until all the vertical spaces are of equal height, after which they are all stretched until there is no more unused space on the page.

The example below using `\vspace` with stretchable *lengths* does not work as desired. The actual space becomes the base value (`5ex` or `15ex`) **plus** `1fill` (which is the same for both instances of `\vspace`), thus resulting in mismatched lengths of vertical space regardless of the amount of space available on the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Some stuff\par
  \vspace{5ex plus 1fill}
  More stuff\par
  \vspace{15ex plus 1fill}
  Even more stuff\par
\end{document}
```

Replacing the `\vspace` commands above with `\addvspace{5ex}\addvspace{0pt plus 1fill}` does not help.

Comment: I've deleted my comments, which are now outdated. However, your request is still contradictory.

Comment: @egreg: I've done the same. I don't see the contradiction (unless you mean the now removed comments, where there was a misunderstanding on my part), but I do realise my expression is not very clear. Do you have any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: Suppose that besides the 20ex of minimum vertical space you have to fill another 1ex. You can't have equal spaces; at most you can add 1ex to the first 5ex of space and leave the 15ex at the minimum. You can have equal spaces in both places only if you have to fill at least 10ex more.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out. I (believe I) have now corrected the question to get rid of the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps as taken from http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/_005caddvspace.html

`\addvspace`
Synopsis:

`\addvspace`{vert-length}
Add a vertical space of vert-length. However, if there are two or more `\addvspace` in a sequence then together they only add the space needed to make the natural length equal to the maximum of the vert-length’s in that sequence. This command is fragile (see `\protect`). The vert-length is a rubber length (see Lengths).

This example illustrates. The picture draws a scale. In a standard LaTeX article the length `\baselineskip` is 12pt. The two rules here are 22pt apart: the sum of the `\baselineskip` and the 10pt from the first `\addvspace`.

Now uncomment the second `\addvspace`. It does not make the gap 20pt longer; instead the gap is the sum of `\baselineskip` and 20pt. So `\addvspace` in a sense does the opposite of its name — it makes sure that multiple vertical spaces do not accumulate, but instead that only the largest one is used.

LaTeX uses this command to adjust the vertical space above or below an environment that starts a new paragraph. For instance, a theorem environment begins and ends with `\addvspace` so that two consecutive theorem’s are separated by one vertical space, not two.

A error ‘Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item` pointing to an `\addvspace` means that you were not in vertical mode when you hit this command. One way to change that is to precede `\addvspace` with a `\par` command (see `\par`), as in the above example.

```latex
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{color}
    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{2pt}%
    \noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \multiput(0,0)(0,-1){25}{{\color{blue}\line(1,0){1}}}
      \multiput(0,0)(0,-5){6}{{\color{red}\line(1,0){2}}}
    \end{picture}%
    \rule{0.25\linewidth}{0.1pt}% 
    \par\addvspace{10pt}% \addvspace{20pt}%
    \par\noindent\rule{0.25\linewidth}{0.1pt}%
 \end{document}
```

Result with one `\addvspace` enabled
[image]

Result with both `\addvspace` enabled

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately `\addvspace` doesn't seem to be the answer. It doesn't work as desired when stretching to `fill`. When stating `\addvspace{0ex plus 1fill}\addvspace{5ex}`, the result is a space of `5ex` **plus** a `fill` stretch, **not** a `fill` that "gobbles" or "contains" the `5ex` space when spanning more than `5ex`.

Comment: Do kindly explain the details of the output that you desire--that would help in finding a solution

Comment: I've tried to do that in the question itself. It is quite understandable to me, but perhaps I'm blinded by the fact that it is written by me. How can I clarify it for you (and others)?

Comment: I've edited the original question to add another way of explaining the problem. Is it more clear to you now?